# How would you write B1 in dialogue?

Tags: orthography

Are there any rules regarding how to write model numbers or serial numbers in dialogue? For example, B1.

"B one."

"B1."

Or "B-one."

Comment: I would write: B1.

Comment: As you apparently did.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter. Whether this is for fiction, or for something factual, it still doesn't matter. The only exception is that when people read it back they don't read something that isn't B1.

Comment: Yes. Outside regular spelling, there are no pronunciation rules. The final sentence above should be taken as The Rule: write it down so anybody reading it aloud would read it correctly. That's the sole purpose.